# Using bootstrap grid set up and my 2nd element is being pushed under my first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am a brand new developer working on a small project and have come across an issue with my coding and the grid system of bootstrap 3.

This is how the site is being displayed. If u look you see the chat box is being pushed to under the video player. I would like the chat box to sit beside the video player.

[image]

This is my HTML and my CSS. It's messy I know. I will work on making it clean tommorow.

Dedication.gg - Home
            
            
            
            
            
                }
                }

```
    <body id="padding"  background="images/bgimage.jpg" style="max-width:200px ">

        <!--Header---->

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inner pull-left" id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="container pull-left">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left">dedication.gg</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Build orders</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Learning Resources</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope white align:center"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!--End of Header---->

        <!--Twitch Video Source --->
            <div class="row-fluid" id="center">
                <div class="col-lg-pull-6">
                    <div class="container">
                        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="600" width="984" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=twitchplayspokemon" bgcolor="#000000">
                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                            <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                            <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf">
                            <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25">
                        </object>
                        <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from TwitchPlaysPokemon on www.twitch.tv</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!--End of Twitch Video Source --- Start of Twitch Chat Box--->
                <div class="col-sm-pull-6" id="center-chatbox&gt;
                &lt;div class=" container"="" "="">
                    <iframe frameborder="2" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;popout_chat=true" height="600" width="350"></iframe>
                </div>

                <!--End of Twitch Chat Box--->
            </div>
        </div>

        <p id="footer-text"> Want a image or video taken down? Contact me through <a href="dedicationsc2@outlook.com">dedicationsc2@outlook.com </a></p>


    </body></html>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
#header {

    border-bottom-width:5px;
    border-bottom-color:black;
    background-color:#000000;

}

#padding{
     padding-top:120px;
     padding-left: 90px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 90px;
     position:relative;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-attachment:fixed;
}

#padding2 {
    padding-top:120px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 12px;

    margin-left:1200px;
    position:relative;

}

#time {
    color:white;
}




p {
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;

}   

body {
overflow:visible;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-size:80px;
color:#FFF;

}

white {
    color: white;

}


h4 {
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;


}   


#page-header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px
}

#panel-body {

    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

#article-text {
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    padding: 5px;

    }

#sidebar-text {
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    padding: 5px;

    }


#h3 {

font-family:  Trebuchet MS;


}

#datetext {
font-style: italic;
}

#center {
     margin-left: 0px;
     right: 90px;
}

#center-chatbox {
    right: 700px;
}
```

Comment: i think `#center {
     margin-left: 0px;
     right: 90px;
}

#center-chatbox {
    right: 700px;
}` is causing the problem, remove the right property and try to use col-lg-offset-*

Comment: Sadly, after trying your solution. It has not fixed the issue.

Comment: `<div class="col-sm-pull-6" id="center-chatbox&gt;
                    &lt;div class=" container"="" "="">` your syntax is wrong

Comment: I have fixed this, this was strangely altered by possibly one of the few validaters i have tried. Still has not changed the issue at all however.

Comment: its your css which is messing it up. can u paste a fiddle link?

Comment: I have no experience using fiddle, but here is the link. http://jsfiddle.net/dcVP4/ If i need to do more then just post in the css and html just say.

Comment: `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="600" width="984"` can u reduce the width and check

Comment: Doing that does not fix anything, just makes the video player smaller. The chat box still refuses to move beside it.

Comment: I have to go out now, however thanks a lot for helping me out. I will be back in around four hours.

Comment: check http://www.bootply.com/114727

Comment: Thank you! You have fixed it. Could i ask what you changed mainly?

Comment: i will post it as an answer. cmpare with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works.

```
    <!--Header---->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inner pull-left" id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container pull-left">
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left">dedication.gg</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Build orders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Learning Resources</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope white align:center"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--End of Header---->

    <!--Twitch Video Source --->
        <div class="row" id="center">
          <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=twitchplayspokemon" bgcolor="#000000" height="600" width="500">
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf">
                        <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25">
                    </object>
                    <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from TwitchPlaysPokemon on www.twitch.tv</a>
                </div>



            <!--End of Twitch Video Source --- Start of Twitch Chat Box--->
            <div class="col-md-6" id="center-chatbox">

                <iframe id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;popout_chat=true" frameborder="2" height="600" scrolling="no" width="350"></iframe>
            </div>
         </div>
            <!--End of Twitch Chat Box--->
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="footer-text"> Want a image or video taken down? Contact me through <a href="dedicationsc2@outlook.com">dedicationsc2@outlook.com </a></p>
```

CSS

```
#header {

    border-bottom-width:5px;
    border-bottom-color:black;
    background-color:#000000;

}

#padding{
     padding-top:120px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     position:relative;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-attachment:fixed;
}

#padding2 {
    padding-top:120px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 12px;

    margin-left:1200px;
    position:relative;

}

#time {
    color:white;
}




p {
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;

}   

body {
overflow:visible;
font-family:Helvetica;
font-size:80px;
color:#FFF;

}

white {
    color: white;

}


h4 {
    font-family:"Helvetica";
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    padding:0px;


}   


#page-header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px
}

#panel-body {

    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

#article-text {
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    padding: 5px;

    }

#sidebar-text {
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    padding: 5px;

    }


#h3 {

font-family:  Trebuchet MS;


}

#datetext {
font-style: italic;
}

#center {
     margin-left: 0px;

}

#center-chatbox {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have use your code its fine now

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
        <title>Dedication.gg - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\Style\style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\css\bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" <meta="" http-equiv="content-type">

    </head>

    <body>

   <div class="col-md-8" style="float:left; width:600px; margin-right:20px;"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="600" width="600" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=twitchplayspokemon" bgcolor="#000000">
                            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                            <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                            <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf">
                            <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25">
                        </object>
                        <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from TwitchPlaysPokemon on www.twitch.tv</a></div>

       <div class="col-md-4"><iframe frameborder="2" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;popout_chat=true" height="600" width="350"></iframe></div>



    </body></html>
```

Comment: If you look into my coding, this has already been done. It is still happening.

Comment: can you share live website link?

Comment: I have no server or domain live yet.

Comment: there are many mistakes in your html and you have used many nested container remove them first instead of outer one

Comment: The containers are just making it so that my site scales with resolution, and then that eventually goes into a mobile format. I will mess around with changing the containers around and removing them and such. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: <!--End of Twitch Video Source --- Start of Twitch Chat Box--->
                    <div class="col-sm-pull-6" id="center-chatbox&gt;
                    &lt;div class=" container"="" "="">


there are many mistakes in html see the above line these should be like below
<!--End of Twitch Video Source --- Start of Twitch Chat Box--->
        <div class="col-sm-pull-6" id="center-chatbox">
         <div class="container">

Comment: I have realized that the HTML cleaner i used once actually messed up a bunch of my code. Making so many errors, however fixing those have not fixed my error.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the code, however the same problem still exists. http://i.imgur.com/RgZzJ6i.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have too many nested containers.  You need to remove all but the outer ones.

Your twitch chat box has some strange things going on with double quotes.

You have mismatched the `col-lg` and `col-sm`.  They need to be the same.

Your glyphicon `align:center` will not work.

There are various other issues with your html markup.  You should run it through a validator ([w3c is good](http://validator.w3.org/)).

Try this...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inner pull-left" id="header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left">dedication.gg</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Build orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Learning Resources</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope white"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--End of Header-->

<!--Twitch Video Source -->
    <div class="row" id="center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="600" width="984" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=twitchplayspokemon" bgcolor="#000000">
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf">
                    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=twitchplayspokemon&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=25">
                </object>
                <a href="http://www.twitch.tv/twitchplayspokemon" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline; text-align:center;">Watch live video from TwitchPlaysPokemon on www.twitch.tv</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- End of Twitch Video Source --- Start of Twitch Chat Box -->
        <div class="col-md-4" id="center-chatbox">
            <iframe frameborder="2" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchplayspokemon&popout_chat=true" height="600" width="350"></iframe>
        </div>

        <!--End of Twitch Chat Box -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This changed a lot.. for the worst. http://imgur.com/xLxPlj6 The chat box is now gone, the header is messed up.